# Ionic flexbox collapsible menu

Tags: css, layout, ionic-framework, flexbox

I'm using Ionic and flexbox for the first time and I'm strugling to organize my layout.

I'm trying to do a vertical menu where the user can select one topic. Each topic has his own subtopics. If one topic is selected a new row should appear with the related subtopics. The topics should be listed side by side.

[image]

The problem is... 
I'm using a row and col-50 to draw the topics side by side, and adding another row inside each col-50 with a col-100. The subtopics row becomes restricted by the parent col-50, not using the 100% width.

[image]

What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i find it this, maybe you looking for [ionic menu using flexbox](http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-complex-layouts-in-ionic/)

It is complete, i apply this for my project [ionic menu with flexbox](http://codepen.io/joseadrianpe/pen/VYJKMQ?editors=1100)

This my menu

[image: My menu customize]

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicLoading) {

});
```